# CL: help identify profiler output

Tags: profiling, common-lisp

What CL implementation (or a profiling package) is he using in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561109/common-lisp-compiling-and-execution-time?rq=1) to show a breakdown by function name?? I have CCL, SBCL, ECL and their `(time (load ...` goes something like that:

```
? (time (load "../e/3.cl"))
(LOAD "../e/3.cl")
took 3,176 milliseconds (3.176 seconds) to run.
        18 milliseconds (0.018 seconds, 0.57%) of which was spent in GC.
During that period, and with 2 available CPU cores,
       128 milliseconds (0.128 seconds) were spent in user mode
       224 milliseconds (0.224 seconds) were spent in system mode
 11,904,264 bytes of memory allocated.
 1,582 minor page faults, 77 major page faults, 0 swaps.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look for metering or profiling in Common Lisp.

Above is the metering tool, which was originally distributed from Mark Kantrowitz' collection of tools: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/tools/metering/0.html

There should be newer versions now.